# sql query for next 4 month displaying

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to print next four months data from sql server

```
column_name
2016-10-31
2016-07-31
2016-08-31
2016-09-30
2017-10-31
2015-07-31
2019-08-31
2017-09-30
2016-11-30
```

I want to output like this

```
2016-10-31
2016-08-31
2016-09-30
2016-11-30
```

Current query:

```
SELECT relieve_date 
FROM table 
WHERE DATEPART(m, relieve_date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +4, getdate())) AND DATEPART(yyyy, relieve_date) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

Comment: Something like this:  `where col >= getdate() and col <= dateadd(month, 6, getdate())`

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. I want a horse with 8 legs, but you can't always get what you want.

Comment: i tried below query,,,SELECT relieve_date 
FROM table
WHERE DATEPART(m, relieve_date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +4, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, relieve_date) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))

Comment: @Gordon Linoff:above query is tried where col >= getdate() and col <= dateadd(month, 6, getdate()) but it printing currrent month also,, i want to print next four month that means(aug,sep,oct,november) only,, but above query is printing(july,aug,sep,oct,november)

Comment: If you know how to use `DATEADD()` already, then why haven't you simply used it to get results from Aug-Nov instead of July-Nov???    It's just one more DATEADD().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is close, but needs a range (`<=`,`>=`) instead of `=`.  You also won't need the year section if you use `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT relieve_date 
FROM   table 
WHERE  relieve_date >= DATEADD(month, 1, getdate())
AND    relieve_date <= DATEADD(month, 4, getdate())
```

Another option is `BETWEEN`, which uses (`<=`,`>=`) logic too:

```
SELECT relieve_date 
FROM   table 
WHERE  relieve_date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, 1, getdate()) AND DATEADD(month, 4, getdate())
```

Comment: if i want next six months in sql query

Comment: @venkat No problem.  One tip though.. always add your query to your question from the start, it will be better received. :)  And for 6 months - just change the 4 in `DATEADD(month, 4, getdate())` to a 6, or however many upcoming months you wish to see.